# Edit delete row Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make the edit in   echo"".$test['**edit**'].""; have a link to a edit page where i can edit the details. also to add a delete check box.

i have the pages made .I just need this link to function to complete the process

```
                         <thead>
                         <tr>
                         <th>TM Code</th>
                         <th>First Name</th>
                         <th>Surname</th>
                         <th>Nickname</th>
                         <th>Telephone</th>
                         <th>Email</th>
                         <th>Department</th>
                         <th>Action</th>

                         </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                         <tr>
                         <?php

                         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crm where dept 
     = 'Telemarketing'");

                         while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                         {
                         $id = $test['id']; 
                         echo"<td>".$test['tm_code']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['tm_firstname']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['tm_surname']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['tm_known']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['tm_phone']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['user_email']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['dept']."</td>";
                         echo"<td>".$test['edit']."</td>";




                         echo "</tr>";
                         }
                         mysql_close($conn);
                         ?>
                        </table>
```

Comment: wrapping it in a link doesn't work? `echo"<td> <a href='...'>".$test['edit']."</a></td>";`

Comment: it has to collect the id of row as well , ive tried this but does not work... echo"<td> <a href="tm_edit.php?id=<?=$test[$i]['id']?>">Edit</a></td>";